# How to enforce semicolon in Typescript interface

Tags: javascript, typescript

Both `,`(comma) and `;`(semicolon) are valid syntax while declaring a typescript interface e.g the below are both valid

```typescript
export interface IUser {
  name: string;
  email: string;
  id: number;
}
```

```typescript
export interface IUser {
  name: string,
  email: string,
  id: number
}
```

Below is my concern as it is also valid. Mixing of `,` and `;` also works

```typescript
export interface IUser {
  name: string;
  email: string,
  id: number;
}
```

Now for consistency I would like to enforce use of `;` at all occasions. My linting still passes even with semicolon rule enforced for `typescript`.Any ideas how this can be implemented?

**.eslintrc.json**

```json
{
  "root": true,
  "ignorePatterns": [
    "projects/**/*"
  ],
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": [
        "*.ts"
      ],
      "parserOptions": {
        "project": [
          "tsconfig.json",
          "e2e/tsconfig.json"
        ],
        "createDefaultProgram": true
      },
      "extends": [
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/ng-cli-compat",
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/ng-cli-compat--formatting-add-on",
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/process-inline-templates"
      ],
      "rules": {
        "@angular-eslint/component-selector": [
          "error",
          {
            "type": "element",
            "prefix": "app",
            "style": "kebab-case"
          }
        ],
        "@angular-eslint/directive-selector": [
          "error",
          {
            "type": "attribute",
            "prefix": "app",
            "style": "camelCase"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "files": [
        "*.html"
      ],
      "extends": [
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/recommended"
      ],
      "rules": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```json
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: are you looking for this? https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/member-delimiter-style.md

Comment: I updated the link added wrong one

Comment: Thanks @ShubhamSrivastava. The link was very helpful

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In the .eslintrc file, add below rule as mentioned,

```
 "@typescript-eslint/member-delimiter-style": [
            "warn",
            {
                "multiline": {
                    "delimiter": "semi",
                    "requireLast": true
                },
                "singleline": {
                    "delimiter": "semi",
                    "requireLast": false
                }
            }
        ]
```

Accepts three values (or two for singleline):

- comma - each member should be delimited with a comma (,).
- semi - each member should be delimited with a semicolon (;).
- none - each member should be delimited with nothing.

NOTE - this is not an option for singleline because having no delimiter between members on a single line is a syntax error in TS.
requireLast
Determines whether or not the last member in the interface/type should have a delimiter:

- true - the last member must have a delimiter.
- false - the last member must not have a delimiter.

Ref link: [click here](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/member-delimiter-style.md)